# Cannot flush data into child Table using doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Following is my Code snippet, what i am trying to do is insert ID of Parent Table to child table along with inserting Data to the Child table at same time. Following is my code Snippet

```
public function addAction()
{

    $ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    $form = new TestForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost())
    {
        $TestFilter = new TestFilter();
        $test = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Test');
        $form->setInputFilter($TestFilter->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid())
        {

            $test->populate($form->getData());

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($test);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            $TestDetail = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('TestDetail');
            $TestDetail->populate($form->getData());
            $TestDetail->setTest($test);
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($TestDetail);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('test');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

**My Entities are as Follows**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use Test\Entity\Test;

 /**
 * An Test entity.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="testdetail")
 * 
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $fname
 * @property string $lname
 * @property string $description
 * @property datetime $creation_date
 * @property datetime $modification_date
 * 
 * @Annotation\Name("Test_Detail")
 * 
 */
 class TestDetail
 {

 /**
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $first_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $last_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestDetail", inversedBy="test_details")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $test;

public function populate($data)
{
    $this->id = isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : $this->id;
    $this->first_name = isset($data['first_name']) ? $data['first_name'] : $this->first_name;
    $this->last_name = isset($data['last_name']) ? $data['last_name'] : $this->last_name;
    $this->description = isset($data['description']) ? $data['description'] : $this->description;
}

/*
 * Constructor
 */

public function __construct()
{
    $now = new \DateTime("now");
    $this->modification_date = $now;
}

/**
 * Magic getter to retrieve protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property     
 */
public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}

/**
 * Magic setter to save protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}

public function setTest(Test $test)
{
    $this->test = $test;
}

}

 ?>


 <?php

 namespace Test\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Zend\Form\Annotation;

 /**
  * An Test entity.
  * 
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="test")
  * 
  * @property int $id
  * @property string $name
  * @property string $address
  * @property smallint $status
  * @property datetime $creation_date
  * @property datetime $modification_date
  * 
  * @Annotation\Name("Test")
  * 
  */
 class Test 
 {

/**
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $status;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 */
protected $creation_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 */
protected $modification_date;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TestDetail", mappedBy="test", orphanRemoval=true)
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 */
protected $test_details;



  public function populate($data) {
  $this->id = isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : $this->id;
  $this->name = isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : $this->name;
  $this->status = isset($data['status']) ? $data['status'] : $this->status;
}



/*
 * Constructor
 */

public function __construct()
{
    $now = new \DateTime("now");
    $this->creation_date = $now;
    $this->modification_date = $now;
}

/**
 * Magic getter to retrieve protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property     
 */
public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}

/**
 * Magic setter to save protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @param mixed $value
 */
public function __set($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}




}
```

**I am getting this error after Flush**

```
Found entity of type Test\Entity\Test on association Test\Entity\TestDetail#test, but expecting Test\Entity\TestDetail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="test_details")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
*/
protected $test;
```

As you are referring Test entity your target entity should be **Test**. Try above mention code and tell me.

Comment: Tested and checked, this was at 1st annoying later i picked the point i was self referencing to same table.

Answer (score 1):

Look at property TestDetails::test

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestDetail", inversedBy="test_details")
 * 
 * @Annotation\Required(true)
 */
protected $test;
```

You are defining the target entity yo be TestDetail (same class), while you pass an instance of Test to TestDetails::setTest()